# ".Net maui" + "Blazor" + "gRPC service" Android WebException

Tags: c#, android, grpc, grpc-web, maui-blazor

I started to explore the new release of Net.Maui combined with Blazor and gRPC Service using the **"Net Maui Blazor App Template" as Client and "gRPC Service AspNetCore template" as Server**.

So Application is working as well when I'm running under the **"Windows platform"** with no kind of error, **but when I'm running the same application under the "Android platform" the calling to the gRPC server is giving the following error:**

```
Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. WebException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7215 ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7215", DebugException="System.Net.WebException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7215
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
 ---> Java.Net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7215
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 11643
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod(String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:line 17
   at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection.cs:line 535
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.<>c__DisplayClass122_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 398
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__271_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, URL javaUrl, HttpURLConnection httpConnection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestRedirectionState redirectState) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 447
  --- End of managed Java.Net.ConnectException stack trace ---
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7215
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)

  --- End of managed Java.Net.ConnectException stack trace ---
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7215
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, URL javaUrl, HttpURLConnection httpConnection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestRedirectionState redirectState) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 454
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 329
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Web.GrpcWebHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Grpc.Net.Client.Web/GrpcWebHandler.cs:line 165
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.<RunCall>d__72[[AppsShared.Protos.Credentials, AppsShared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AppsShared.Protos.LoginStatus, AppsShared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext() in /_/src/Grpc.Net.Client/Internal/GrpcCall.cs:line 469")
```

Here the settings:

**gRPC Client Channel:**

```
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(services =>
            {
                var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
                return GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7215", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
            });
```

**gRPC Client Call**

```
            var loginer = new Loginer.LoginerClient(channel);
            var loginStatus = await loginer.LoginAsync(new Credentials { Password = password , UserName = userName });
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**Andoid MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Essentials;

namespace MauiBlazorBase
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, 
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
        ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | 
        ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]

    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, 
            [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Thankyou in advance for tips.

Piercarlo

Comment: Your IP localhost/127.0.0.1:7215, try 10.0.0.2 or your IP, not ip localhost